# How to start prallel processing in powershell

Tags: powershell

We want to upload some files to server, this files will be processed by an API, so we want to run multiple threads for file processing and upload.

Have written the powershell script to upload file bunch, but it is running single session at a time instead of running multiple sessions,

```
$count = 0
$nsfFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\FileUpload" |
               Sort -Property Length |
               Select-Object -Property Name
$report = @()
foreach ($nsfFileName in $nsfFileList.Name) {
    $count = $count + 1
    $filesize = (Get-Childitem -Path "D:\FileUpload" -File $nsfFileName).Length/1MB
    $details = @{
        Name = $nsfFileName
        Size = $filesize
        Log_Directory ="D:\Work\logs\$nsfFileName"+".txt"
        Start_Time = get-Date -Format "dd Mm yy | hh mm ss"
    }

    $report = New-Object PSObject -Property $details

    $report | Export-Csv –Append -Path "D:\Work\uploadInProcessReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation

    Start-Process powershell.exe "&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Barracuda\Message Archiver\NSF Importer\NsfDump.exe' -Input 'D:\BaracudaUpload\$nsfFileName' -JobDirectory 'D:\nsfjob' -ApiHost 'test.test.com' -ApiUser 'admin' -ApiPass 'admin' | Out-File 'D:\Work\logs\$nsfFileName.txt'"

    if ($count = 10) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
        $count = 0
    }
}
```

Expecting to get a single for a file in CSV and mutiple sessions of PowerShell for upload, but multiple entries for a single file is updated in CSV and single PowerShell session is running at a time.

Comment: According to `multiple entries for a single file is updated in csv`, have you checked that the list of files is correct?

Comment: You're looking for [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/background-jobs).

Comment: @montonero Yes the list of files is correct, as i m getting the files from gci, and we cant have same name files in a folder

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I believe background jobs aren't the case (although they could help). The script should work fine without them.

Comment: @fmsrv Have you tried to output a current file name? Is it correct?

Comment: @montonero Perhaps. But IMO jobs are a significantly cleaner approach to this problem.

Comment: @montonero yep, I have tried that multiple times, i got the unique name in output

Comment: @fmsrv If you're getting the same name then your list is incorrect. There are no other reasons.

Comment: @montonero You are right, but i m getting multiple entries in csv, m not sure, why it is, even the timestamp is different

Comment: major issue is, why I m not getting multiple sessions of powershell it is running one session than after completeion of that session, it starts second, but i need it to start 10 session at a time

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers As per your answer given in linked question, using Start-process should'nt be making any issue ?? or using a job and start-process makes a difference

Comment: `Start-Job` and `Start-Process` should both work. I'm not quite sure why `Start-Process` doesn't work for you. But given the command you want to run I'd argue that `Start-Job` is the cleaner approach anyway.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers have tried start-job, it is really cleaner approach but still it is also creating only one job, any idea what may be the issue

Comment: @fmsrv Check the array you've got after call of `gci`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers have gone through docs and found by default powershell run command line by line, so may be it will not execute exe in parallel, by little more search I found that powershell has workflow mechanism in which parallel processing can be done, which i am trying, if you have any idea on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj574197(v%3Dws.11)) than let me know

Comment: @fmsrv `Start-Process` launches a new process and unless you specify the parameter `-Wait` that process should run asynchronously (i.e. script execution should continue without waiting for that process to terminate). `Start-Job` does roughly the same. I generally do not recommend using PowerShell workflows unless you know exactly what you're doing. They're considerably slower than regular PowerShell and there are subtle syntactical differences that will bite you.

Comment: Instead of trying to shotgun the problem why don't you edit the question and show the code you currently have, along with a more detailed description of the behavior you observe?